LinkedIn’s link on Facebook, don’t show preview
I used to post on Facebook the link from my LinkedIn’s newsletter but, since a few months ago, don’t show the preview, just show the LinkedIn home url
I was in contact with support but the said is Facebook problem, the thing is that I tried with different links on different Facebook accounts and different computers and the problem is the same, JUST WITH LINKEDIN.
Even that I tried to find a way to contact Support at Facebook, is awful, I didn’t found any way to that
I repeat, the problem is just with LinkedIn links, if I paste links from somewhere else, Works, on the other side, the same link copied, If I paste on email or Whatsapp IT WORKS.
So, the problem is precisely the LinkedIn link pasted in Facebook

You could debug the URL to see if the relevant Open graph meta data is set, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug But if that tool says that it isn't, then there is little you, or anyone here, can do about that - this would be a problem linkedin would have to fix then.
